# Using combobox properties in C# NET 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, combobox

I'd like to know how to set a combobox to be read only,meaning the user cannot write text into it,but just select?

Another question,how to determinate the text of the selected choice.For example it has index of 4 values(10,20,30 and 40).If the user chooce 20,how can I get the Text of the choice he selected(Not the index number,but text)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a list only combobox:

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

to get the text:

```
string text = comboBox.Text;
```